# Passing event parameter when clicking a div in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question is regarding the flow of an `onClick` event in `React` when clicking a `div`.

My application has a `ParentComponent` which calls in to a `ChildComponent` and subsequently creates a `div` for each member of the `props.options` array in the `ParentComponent`.

I have two questions which are as follows:

1. When I click the `div`, how can I pass the `onClick` event to this component?
2. How does the `div` know which `option` created it? I mean to ask, some iteration of the `this.props.options` array, say, `optionA` created, say, `divA`, how does `divA` know that it was created by `optionA` and not `optionB`? Is this done by React internally?

This is my Parent component

```
interface ParentComponentState {
  ..
  ..
}

export interface ParentComponentProps {
 ...
 ...
}

export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<ParentComponentProps, ParentComponentState> {
  public state: ParentComponentState = {
    ...
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  private handleClick = (item) => {
    console.log(item);
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {

    return (
      <>
          <SomeButtonComponent>
            { this.props.options.map((item: any, index: any) => (
              <ChildComponent
                onClick={ () => this.handleClick(item) }
              />
            )) }
          </SomeButtonComponent>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Child component

```
export function ChildComponent(props: IChildComponent): JSX.Element {
  return
    (
      <div
        ref={ ... }
        className={ someClassName }
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: someHTML } }
        onClick={ props.onClick }
      />
    )
}
```

Comment: `onClick={ () => this.handleClick(item) }`=> `onClick={ (event) => this.handleClick(item, event) }`

Comment: @Derek Thanks Derek! Your answer is helpful. But could you please add it as an answer. Also, who is passing the event as argument? in `onClick={ (event) => this.handleClick(item, event) }` ?

Comment: It's the native browser `MouseEvent` that has all the information about the click. When you click the `div` element defined in `ChildComponent`, the browser sends that event object to the function you set to handle it. In this case, the anonymous inline function that becomes `props.onClick`.

Comment: @Derek I tried the change you suggested and see the event. Thanks again! However, I tried with the function signature as private handleClick = (item, event, event1, event2) => {...} and as expected only the argument event has the actual event. My question is: How does the browser know to pass in only the second argument as the actual event? Where is the contract for it? Does the onClick function expect a callback function where the first argument is item and the second is the actual event? Apologies for the questions - since I can't see the call, I am finding it hard to visualize it.

Comment: i suggest you read the MDN documentation on mouse and keyboard event handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first question about passing `event` you can do this:

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<ParentComponentProps, ParentComponentState> {
  public state: ParentComponentState = {
    ...
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  private handleClick = (item) => (event) => { // This is called function currying
    console.log(item);
    console.log(event);
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {

    return (
      <>
          <SomeButtonComponent>
            { this.props.options.map((item: any, index: any) => (
              <ChildComponent
                onClick={ this.handleClick(item) }
              />
            )) }
          </SomeButtonComponent>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

and for your second question if you want to know in `ChildComponent` that which options created it you have to pass another props to `ChildComponent` and send the `option` in `ChildComponent` as a prop and use it there

Comment: thank you for your response. I did look up function currying and understands `event` is an argument to the `handleClick` function. However, who is passing the `event` argument to the `handleClick` function? I am guessing it needs to be passed from the `ChildComponent`. Could you please share how this is done for completeness? Thanks, once again! I am finding your response useful.

Comment: When you pass ```handleClick``` function as a prop to ```ChildComponent``` and then you're using it in ```div``` ```onClick``` event ,

 your ```handleClick``` function is controlled by ```div``` element and ```event``` parameter is send directly from ```div``` to ```handleClick``` function

if you found the answer usefull , I would appreciate upvote and checking it as the right answer ;)

Comment: accepting the answer, thank you! I do have a follow up question, though. When you say, "event parameter is send directly from div to handleClick function".  My question is: Who controls the order of arguments in the invocation of this call? How does the browser know to pass in only the second argument as the actual event? Where is the contract for it? Does the onClick function in the div expect a callback function where the second argument is the actual event? Where is this defined? Sorry, since this happens internally, and I'm not making the call, I am trying to understand.

Comment: I Added another answer because it's a little hard to show what I mean in comment

Answer (score 0):

I would try to answer your questions to the best of my ability, so here it is:

> Who controls the order of arguments in the invocation of this call?

You Do, React Only Says give me function which takes an argument and When an `event` for example `click event` happened I will call your function with and will send the `event` object as the parameter of it.

so it's on you, if you want to have more arguments you need to some how get around this by currying arguments or binding them like below:

```
 handleClick = (item) => (event) => {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(event);
  }
```

when you doing something like this and then in the `onClick` props you're calling the handle click like below:

```
   <ChildComponent onClick={ this.handleClick(item) } />
```

you're actually sending

```
(event) => { 
    console.log(item);
    console.log(event);
  }
```

to your props and this is what React wants(A function which takes an argument and will call it when event happpens)

See [Event Handling in React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

> How does the browser know to pass in only the second argument as the actual event?
>   As I said above, React has its own Event System on top of browser Event System (Read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)),

so the answer to this question is : it doesn't, React only needs a function with on parameter( For better understanding of the work around you need know about javascript `closure` in case you want to use `currying` or javascript `bind` function in case you're using binding )

> Where is the contract for it?

you define in your code

> Does the onClick function in the div expect a callback function where the second argument is the actual event?

No, It just need a function with one parameter, and in case it's confusing to you when using `bind` function, just read bout it a little [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

> Where is this defined?
>   it's one of the `class` parameter, and you need to read about it until you understand it
>   (I recommend using Function Components so you don't need to work with `this` concept in javascript)